# Copy playlists from Winamp to Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, winamp, playlists

I have several large playlists on Winamp that I would like to transfer over to Windows Media Player.

Is it do able? Where are playlists stored? Do I have to convert them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winamp saves playlists in the `.m3u` format. Here's [more info](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/m3u) on M3U files. Your version of WMP should already be able to support this; there's no need to convert your playlists.

You can manually save a copy of your playlist in Winamp by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

[image]

Afterwards, you can just open the file in (or drag it into) Windows Media Player to play it.

Comment: I was looking for something a little more seamless/automated, but this will work for now.  Thanks.